# pointer-events:none but capture click

Tags: javascript, css

is it possible to allow only click and disable all other pointer-events

top-layer has a search bar

bottom-layer has a word cloud

I have set `pointer-events:none` on top-layer, so all words in the word cloud can be hovered over even if they are below the search bar.

but I want the click event on the input text to be enabled, so that when the user wants to type in something, he can.

[image]

[Here is a related fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cob02bpv/)

The text is behind the input, but it should be hoverable, 
the input is above the text, but it should be focusable using mouse, to allow the user to type in.

Note: it looks like a placeholder thing, but it is not. please see the original image to see what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you have code examples? Whats the problem? Whats your setup?

Comment: Per my understanding, if user clicks outside, nothing should happen and focus should remain inside input. Am I right?

Comment: @Rajesh not really, input should only have focus when it is clicked, otherwise it should remain transparent to all events

Comment: It should ONLY be hoverable or event clickable?

Comment: @YoramdeLangen the words below the text box should be hoverable atleast (and clickable if possible) , and the text input should only be clickable

Answer (score 3):

Because `pointer-events` is blocking interactieve events(click, hover, mouseenter etc.) it would be only accessible with javascript (through focus for example).

It's maybe not the best solution but it will do I guess in your case?

```
(function($) {
  var focus = false;
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(focus);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (focus) {
      focus = false;
      $('.cl1').trigger('blur');
    } else {
      focus = true;
      $('.cl1').focus();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

a fiddle with this working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/cob02bpv/1/

Edit: you could check on which element was clicked, only elements under the input will be tricky.

If its not the solution the only one would be to calculate the coordinates from the input box and check where the `click` event was triggered. But still you would have problems for your elements under the input box.

Comment: ok, in this case, even if i click on words which are not below the input text, it would focus the input. also, if i stopPropagation from word click, the document would not get the event. then the user won't be able to click on the text box to activate it, but he can click elsewhere (except the words) to focus the input

Comment: i get it though, it would be difficult to capture both clicks, on the text as well as the word behind it

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work. Listening to the click event on the parent container, getting the `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` values to check if they are within the bounds of the `input` element. If so, you can then set the focus to the `input` element. You can still determine if one of the random words underneath the `input` element has been clicked.

```js
var d = document,
    c = d.getElementsByClassName('container').item(0),
    inp = d.createElement('input'),
    a = 50,
    i = 0;


/*
 | get the clientBoundingRect of the input element
 | and if the mouse x and mouse y positions are within
 | the bounds set the focus on to the input element.
------------------------------------------------------------- */
function inpClickHndl (evt) {
  var inpRect = inp.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = evt.clientX,
      y = evt.clientY,
      l = inpRect.left,
      w = l + inpRect.width,
      t = inpRect.top,
      h = t + inpRect.height;

  if (x >= l && x <= w && y >= t && y <= h) {
    inp.focus();
  }
}

/* 
 | ignore this, it's just to create the random words.
------------------------------------------------------------- */
function wordClickHndl (evt) {
  this.style.color = "yellow";
}

for (i; i < a; i++) {
  var p = d.createElement('p'),
      t = d.createTextNode('Random Word');
  p.appendChild(t);
  p.addEventListener('click', wordClickHndl, false);
  p.style.position = 'absolute';
  p.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 80)) + -40 + 'px';
  p.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 80)) + -40 + 'px';
  p.style.fontSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (38 - 8)) + 8 + 'px';
  p.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  c.appendChild(p);
}

inp.setAttribute('type', 'text');
c.appendChild(inp);

/*------------------------------------------------------------- */

// add a click handler to your parent element.
c.addEventListener('click', inpClickHndl, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.container p {
  color: green;
}

.container p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: calc(50% - 85px);
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: If an element has border-radius (like a circle), it will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `pointer-events` CSS3 property, setting as `initial` to the text box. Using `!important` is recommended also, so because another property can pass that added.

In *CSS3*:

```
pointer-events:initial !important
```

In *JavaScript*:

`document.querySelector('input[type=text]').style.pointerEvents="initial"`

Comment: if i add this, i am not able to hover over the words that are below the text input

Comment: Great job, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If layout permits it you could use the adjacent sibling combinator, given that you re-order the elements:

Tested on FireFox and Chrome.

```css
.backText:hover {
  color           : red;
}
.cl1 {
  opacity         : 0.7;
  position        : absolute;
}
/* adjacent sibling combinator */
.wrap-input:hover + div {
  color           : red;
}
.cl1:focus {
  opacity         : 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrap-input">
    <input type="text" class="cl1" value="aa" />
  </div>
  <div class="backText">
     Some text to be hovered even if input is above
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Other options

The following only works on FireFox. Tested on Chrome and it flickers when pointer is moved, - but could perhaps give some ideas.

Instead of setting `pointer-events` on the input-element directly, set it using the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Example, based on your fiddle:

```css
.cl1 {
  position        : absolute;
  top             : 0px;
  opacity         : 0.7;
  height          : 30px;
}
/* Move pointer-events here */
.cl1:hover {
  pointer-events  : none;
}
.cl1:focus {
  opacity         : 1;
}

.backText:hover {
  color           : red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="backText">
     Some text to be hovered even if input is above
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="cl1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past. I managed to solve it in a bit tricky way, just added parent division with `button` inside and applied `click event` on parent element and `pointer-events: none` to child button element.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easiest to set input's `z-index` to a higher value than the element with `pointer-events: 'none'`?